# Javascript Regular Expression for RGB color validator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to using this RegEx for color validation.

```
colorPattern = /\#([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})/
```

but it return always true

e.g

```
colorPattern.test("#FF0000")
colorPattern.test("#FF0000000")
colorPattern.test("#FF0000mmm000")
```

are always true.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't this more of a hex validator and not an RGB value validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wil probably do what you're looking for:

```
colorPattern = /^\#([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})$/
```

You can also use this to test it out: http://www.gummydev.com/regex/

Comment: Or use this one: http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex which looks a little better :p

Answer (score 1):

```
colorPattern = /^(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3, 6})$/
```

Comment: does {3, 6} not means 3 to 6 Characters?

Comment: It means 3 or 6 characters and not a range.

Comment: {n,m} matches n to m times.